# Getting each element in Pandas crosstab

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab, contingency

I have a dataset given below:

```
a,b,c
1,1,1
1,1,1
1,1,2
2,1,2
2,1,1
2,2,1
```

I created crosstab with pandas:

```
 cross_tab = pd.crosstab(index=a, columns=[b, c], rownames=['a'], colnames=['b', 'c'])
```

my crosstab is given as an output:

```
b        1     2
c        1  2  1
a        
1        2  1  0
2        1  1  1
```

I want to iterate over this crosstab for given each a,b and c values. How can I get values such as `cross_tab[a=1][b=1, c=1]`? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [slicers](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#using-slicers):

```
a,b,c = 1,1,1
idx = pd.IndexSlice
print (cross_tab.loc[a, idx[b,c]])
2
```

You can also reshape `df` by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html), [`reorder_levels`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reorder_levels.html) and then use [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
a = cross_tab.unstack().reorder_levels(('a','b','c'))
print (a)
a  b  c
1  1  1    2
2  1  1    1
1  1  2    1
2  1  2    1
1  2  1    0
2  2  1    1
dtype: int64

print (a.loc[1,1,1])
2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have another problem now. It returns error if I give print(cross_tab2.loc[2,2,2]). How can I get values of a,b and c in a crosstab?

Comment: Do you want loop by `a` ? Or if `print(cross_tab2.loc[2,2,2])` what is desired output?

Comment: I actually I want to loop over all possible combinations for a,b,c. Or I can loop for all values of a,b,c that exists in crosstab.

Comment: Is possible use `for (a,b,c), x in a.iteritems():
    print (a,b,c)
    print (x)` ?

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for `df2.xxx.get_level_values`:

```
In [777]: cross_tab.loc[cross_tab.index.get_level_values('a') == 1,\
                        (cross_tab.columns.get_level_values('b') == 1)\
                      & (cross_tab.columns.get_level_values('c') == 1)]
Out[777]: 
b  1
c  1
a   
1  2
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to consider, albeit at loss of a little bit of readability, might be to simply use the `.loc` to navigate the hierarchical index generated by `pandas.crosstab`.  Following example illustrates it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1234)

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "a": np.random.choice([1, 2], 5, replace=True),
        "b": np.random.choice([11, 12, 13], 5, replace=True),
        "c": np.random.choice([21, 22, 23], 5, replace=True),
    }
)
df
```

Output

```
    a   b   c
0   2   11  23
1   2   11  23
2   1   12  23
3   2   12  21
4   1   12  21
```

`crosstab` output is:

```
cross_tab = pd.crosstab(
    index=df.a, columns=[df.b, df.c], rownames=["a"], colnames=["b", "c"]
)
cross_tab

b   11  12
c   23  21  23
a           
1   0   1   1
2   2   1   0
```

Now let's say you want to access value when `a==2`, `b==11` and `c==23`, then simply do

```
cross_tab.loc[2].loc[11].loc[23]

2
```

Why does this work?  `.loc` allows one to select by index *labels*.  In the dataframe output by `crosstab`, our *erstwhile column values now become index labels*.  Thus, with every `.loc` selection we do, it gives the slice of the dataframe corresponding to that index label.  Let's navigate `cross_tab.loc[2].loc[11].loc[23]` step by step:

```
cross_tab.loc[2]
```

yields:

```
b   c 
11  23    2
12  21    1
    23    0
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

Next one:

```
cross_tab.loc[2].loc[11]
```

Yields:

```
c
23    2
Name: 2, dtype: int64
```

And finally we have

```
cross_tab.loc[2].loc[11].loc[23]
```

which yields:

2

Why do I say that this reduces the readability a bit?  Because to understand this selection you have to be aware of how the crosstab was created, i.e. rows are `a` and columns were in the order `[b, c]`.  You have to know that to be able to interpret what `cross_tab.loc[2].loc[11].loc[23]` would do.  But I have found that often to be a good tradeoff.